# Is there a way to add OS info into header(or some other places) to make a GET/POST request look like coming from certain system?

Tags: python, header, http-headers, urllib2

For example, I can easily "make" the request from FireFox:

```
import urllib2

header = {"User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 5.1; rv:14.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/14.0.1"}
req = urllib2.request("http://google.com", None, header)
response = urllib2.urlopen(req)
```

I was wondering, is there a way to add OS info into the header or somewhere else to make it look like coming from a certain OS?

Comment: The User Agent string already tells the server the originating OS (see the Windows NT part).

Comment: Just use user agent, you can google what all the possible user agent strings are and go from there. Each browser on each platform has its own unique user agent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The OS is also in the user agent string. Try the string below.

```
Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux i686; rv:10.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/10.0
```

More details on the user agent: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Gecko_user_agent_string_reference